# Why "select" does not return true value or is it?

Tags: ruby

```
[1,2,5,8,3].collect{|i| i.to_s} #=> ["1", "2", "5", "8", "3"]
```

Whereas

```
[1,2,5,8,3].select{|i| i.to_s} #=> [1, 2, 5, 8, 3]
```

As per ruby-doc `select => "Returns a new array containing all elements of ary for which the given block returns a true value."`

Isn't the true value here should be `i.to_s` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby anything order than `nil` or `false` is `true`

So:

`[1,2,5,8,3].select{|i| i.to_s}` is equivalent to `[1,2,5,8,3].select{|i| true }`

which would both evaluate to:

```
[1,2,5,8,3].select{|i| i.to_s} #=> [1, 2, 5, 8, 3]
[1,2,5,8,3].select{|i| true } #=> [1, 2, 5, 8, 3]
```

as you said in the question

> select => "Returns a new array containing all elements of ary for
>   which the given block returns a true value.

So select would return the original array since the block always evaluates to true.

However `collect`

```
Returns a new array with the results of running block once for every element in enum.
```

So:

```
[1,2,5,8,3].collect{|i| i.to_s} #=> ["1", "2", "5", "8", "3"]
[1,2,5,8,3].collect{|i| true } #=> [true, true, true, true, true]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `#select` the only selects the values from the array, when block is evaluated to non-`false`, and returns the new array:

```
{|i| i.to_s } # => false|nil or non-false|nil
```

while `#collect` generates the new array by appying block to each of current array values:

```
{|i| i.to_s } # => i.to_s => "String"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `#collect` as a *map* operation and `#select` as a *filter*, hence `#select`'s return value is always a subset of the initial array.